# Finding a specific max value

Tags: python, string, list

I've got a string of data that has temperature, time, and other numbers in the list. Now I'm looking to find the max temperature and the times that max temperature occurred. I can only find the max value which falls under the other numbers I'm not concerned with atm.

```
>>> s = re.findall('\d+',data)
>>> max.s
```

This is how I'm finding my max value. Is there a way to just get the max temperature.
The data is sorted by time, Some Sample data.

```
    05:00,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,31
    05:01,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,30
    05:02,8.9,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,29
    05:03,8.9,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,30
    05:04,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,21
    05:05,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,26
    05:06,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,25
    05:07,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,30
    05:08,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,29
    05:09,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,33
    05:10,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,28
```

So i'm looking to get the time(s) that the max temp was recorded.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Pass your list of data through [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) with the key representing the temperature (if second column, it will be `1`), and get the last row.

Comment: @metatoaster That would be `O(NlogN)`, we can do this on `O(N)` time.

Comment: @user What's your expected output?

Comment: output should look like (maxtemp, ['time1', 'time2'...etc])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `max()` here to get the max temperature  first and and then later later iterate over each line to get the times:

```
>>> s = '''05:00,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,31
05:01,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,30
05:02,8.9,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,29
05:03,8.9,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,30
05:04,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,21
05:05,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,26
05:06,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,25
05:07,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,30
05:08,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,29
05:09,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,33'''
>>> data = s.splitlines()      #splits data into lines
>>> max_temp = max(data, key=lambda x:float(x.split(',')[1])).split(',')[1]
>>> max_temp
'9.0'
>>> [x[0] for x in (line.split(',') for line in data) if max_temp == x[1]]
['05:00', '05:01', '05:04', '05:05', '05:06', '05:07', '05:08', '05:09']
```

Comment: @user3491814 Can you post some actual sample data in question body? I presumed it to be stored in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import re

res = []
t = []
a = ['05:00,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,31',
     '05:01,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,30']
for i in a:
    res.append(re.findall('\d+:\d+', i)[0])
    res.append(re.findall('\d+\.\d+', i)[0])

temp = res[1::2]


maxTemp = max(temp)

for i in xrange(1, len(res), 2):
    if res[i] == maxTemp:
        t.append(res[i-1])
print 'final result is ', (maxTemp, t)
```